# Spring Cloud Feign client with Hystrix circuit-breaker timeout defaults in 2 seconds

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-cloud-feign

**Reproducible through a project on GitHub: [spring-cloud-feign-hystrix-timeout-problem](https://github.com/Nikolas-Charalambidis/spring-cloud-feign-hystrix-timeout-problem)**

---

I am using Spring Boot `2.3.1.RELEASE` with Spring Cloud `Hoxton.SR6`. Namely Feign client and Hystrix without Zuul and Eureka to fetch REST responses.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
   <version>Hoxton.SR6</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then I use use the following  dependencies on top of Spring Boot `2.3.1.RELEASE` and `Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR6`:

- `org.springframework.boot`:`spring-boot-starter`
- `org.springframework.boot`:`spring-boot-starter-web`
- `org.springframework.cloud`:`spring-cloud-starter-openfeign`
- `org.springframework.cloud`:`spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix`

I enable `@EnableFeignClients` and `@EnableCircuitBreaker` and use a `@FeignClient` with a simple fallback to log and rethrow an exception:

```
@FeignClient(name="my-feign", url = "${feign.url}", fallbackFactory = MyFallbackFactory.class) {
public interface MyFeignClient {

    @PostMapping(value = "/api/dto")
    postDto(@RequestBody Dto dto);
}
```

With the following `application.yml` the timeout is around **1 second** because Hystrix defaults to the very same value:

```
feign:
  hystrix:
    enabled: true
  client:
    config:
      default:
        connectTimeout: 5000
        readTimeout: 5000
```

> 11:52:05.493 INFO  10200 --- [nio-8060-exec-2] com.mycompany.rest.MyController       : Calling REST right now!
>
> 11:52:06.538 ERROR 24044 --- [nio-8060-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: MyFeignClient#postDto(Dto) timed-out and fallback failed.] with root cause

---

**What I tried?**

As long as I add the following lines to increase the timeouts to 60 seconds, the timeout become effectively around **2 seconds**:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        timeout:
          enabled: true
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
```

> 11:53:33.590  INFO 16052 --- [nio-8060-exec-2] com.mycompany.rest.MyController       : Calling REST right now!
>
> 11:53:35.614 ERROR 16052 --- [nio-8060-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: MyFeignClient#postDto(Dto) failed and fallback failed.] with root cause

The call falls into fallback right in **2 seconds** as long as the Hystrix read/connect timeouts have been increased. However I expect to achieve **5 seconds** as long as I declared it in `feign.client.config.default...` timeouts. I feel I am missing another configuration.

**Q: How to increase the timeout?**

---

**Edit:**

- `mvn dependency:tree`: https://pastebin.com/LJFGaMTc
- `pom.xml`: https://pastebin.com/98uXHTaR
- Stack-trace: https://pastebin.com/7rQweC8w

Comment: I dont know if this help, can you please check feign config at last in this file https://gitlab.com/spring-boot-cloud-samples/spring-boot-microservice-resilience4j/-/blob/master/web-api/src/main/resources/application.yml

Comment: @silentsudo: Thanks! `feign.client.config.default...` applies to all the services and I have no further configuration. I also don't use Resilience4j but Hystrix. Does my question follow minimal and reproducible example?

Comment: Any downvote reason? What is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration is correct and what you are describing is expected behavior. The issue here is that exception with `Connection refused` isn't thrown after your configured timeout -- 10 seconds. Instead, it is thrown immediately after Java's internal socket implementation finds that server host is not reachable. In simplest case, the server you are calling isn't up and running.

As to why there is a second increase after you set the hystrix timeout, you can debug hystrix's call stack to find out that `HystrixRuntimeException` isn't being thrown in the same order.

Before your custom hystrix timeout, hystrix had a default timeout of 1 second, which means this runtime exception is always thrown once one second since execution has lapsed, regardless whether the request succeeds or fails. So in your case, `Connection refused` could very likely happen after `HystrixTimeoutException`. After you set the timeout be to longer than that of feign client, `HystrixTimeoutException` only gets created **after** a feign exception is thrown (due to "Connection refused"), hence the delay.

```
// 'cause' should be different due to timing
public HystrixRuntimeException(... Exception cause, Throwable fallbackException)
```

To simulate the timeout, I'd say you could force a timeout on the server, such as `Thread.sleep(6000)` to halt the execution on server side, or simply do a breakpoint while on debugger.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can reproduce 5 seconds timeout when the service is available with `Thread.sleep(6000)`. However, the configuration names would make me think that the `Thread.sleep(6000)` causes *read timeout* while a not-available-service causes *connection timeout* - both defined as 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes. The property names don't fully convey what goes on at the networking level. There are subtle differences. Say the client tries to connect to the server. It first tries to do a look up and sends a packet to the host, and since your server is not even running,  it will send back immediately a packet that results in "connection refused". On the other hand, connection timeout happens client sends a packet but never received anything in return.

Comment: -- Continue Above -- This usually happens during the initial connection with the running server, where the server takes more than allotted client timeout to respond. In your case, this would be hard to reproduce because `Thread.sleep(6000)` causes the read timeout and not the connection timeout as an initial connection has been established.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I still would like to find out where are the 2 seconds configuraed (it is not a random number, it's always 2 secconds straight). I'll accept your answer and make you a winner of the bounty by its end.

Comment: @Nikolas You are getting a consistent 2 second because all the intermediate executions prior to HystrixTimeoutException getting thrown aren't changed. A large part of 2 second is caused by time it took to do a look up, and received a packet resulting in "Connection refused".  This 2 second could be subject to change by quite a bit if you switch from `localhost:8090` to a broken remote host that involves a DNS lookup.

Comment: continue -- Remember in your first case, you are getting consistent runtime error after one second because of hystrix default timeout, even though the actual error of `Connection refused` takes place one second after. HystrixTimeoutException simply wraps whatever runtime exception that comes first and throw a instance of itself.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can try is to define the configuration property of the Hystrix timeout in a single line (I know that it should be equivalent to the nested definition you proposed in your YAML file, but sometimes I came across properties that only were loaded in this way). As you can [see](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/6d4686624e732247cab4ede05ef453783fd6f257/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/src/test/resources/application.yml) in their tests, this is the way Spring Cloud itself configures Hystrix timeout:

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 5000
```

Also, although you indicated that you are not using Zuul or Eureka, please, verify if you are using Ribbon in any way, there is some dependencies (see https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1778 and https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1324) between the Hystrix and Ribbon timeouts.

If it is the case, you must configure the timeouts of both libraries:

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 5000
ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 5000
  ReadTimeout: 5000
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First of all, I have tried both inline and YAML formats of the configuration. I have set `ribbon.ConnectTimeout` and `ribbon.ReadTimeout` to 5000, however the request falls to Hystrix fallback in just 2 seconds, not 5. Note I don't import `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon`, however, `spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon` is present as a transitive dependency. Finally, I have tried both explicitely importing this dependency and/or exluding from the present ones.

Comment: I see @Nikolas. Can you please post your Hystrix command definition?

Comment: I don't use `@HystrixCommand` annotation but a fallbackFactory class implementing `FallbackFactory<T>`... it is linked in `@FeignClient` (in my question). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Exactly, this class is what I mean, just for trying to reproduce the error. Please, can you also expand the root cause of the stack trace of the runtimeexception elevated by Hystrix? On the other hand, you are only using configuration properties, aren't you? What troubles me is why defining the timeout of Hyxtrix to 60 seconds makes the actual timeout happens every 2 seconds. Why 2 seconds and not other amount of time? How are you simulating failover?

Comment: Aside from including the stacktrace, I will also publish a project to GitHub reproducing this issue and to keep the question clean (later after I come home from work). I use standard `application.yml` and nothing else (no beans aside from the fallback, which is invoked *after* the 2 seconds timeout). I also wonder why there are two seconds. Stay in touch.

Comment: I have included the full stack-trace + GitHub repository where you can reproduce the error: https://github.com/Nikolas-Charalambidis/spring-cloud-feign-hystrix-timeout-problem

Comment: Thanks for the effort! You answer is indeed helpful to understand the relationship between these dependencies.

Comment: You are welcome. The another answer seems right. This is why I said that if you could show the full exception stacktrace. This timeout raised by plain socket was very helpful in order to understand the problem.